# System.Drawing.Bitmap in the .NET Portable Framework

Tags: c#, porting, portable-class-library

As exercise, I'm trying to port [Overv/SteamWebAPI](https://github.com/Overv/SteamWebAPI) to a Portable Class Library. However, one of the functions returns a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, which is not available in the .NET Portable subset.

Considering the function below, what would be the best alternative? Due to the nature of the project, I'm not concerned about backward compatiblity.

The function in question:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieve the avatar of the specified user in the specified format.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="user">User</param>
/// <param name="size">Requested avatar size</param>
/// <returns>The avatar as bitmap on success or null on failure.</returns>
public Bitmap GetUserAvatar(User user, AvatarSize size = AvatarSize.Small)
{
    if (user.avatarUrl.Length == 0) return null;

    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        Stream stream;
        if (size == AvatarSize.Small)
            stream = client.OpenRead(user.avatarUrl + ".jpg");
        else if (size == AvatarSize.Medium)
            stream = client.OpenRead(user.avatarUrl + "_medium.jpg");
        else
            stream = client.OpenRead(user.avatarUrl + "_full.jpg");

        Bitmap avatar = new Bitmap(stream);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();

        return avatar;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Portable Class Library does [not contain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) graphics nor web client support.

If this is the only offending method, maybe you can discard this only method in your portable library. Alternatively, you could consider returning the *Stream*, although you would still need to find a workaround for reading the bitmap from the web.

**UPDATE**

As far as I can tell, the method can be made static. Thus, another alternative would be to create additional platform specific (.NET, Silverlight, WP7) libraries for the non-portable code and move this method to a static class in the platform specific libraries. If you make the method an extension method, you will be able to use the method without modifications in your client code. Except, of course, that the method should return [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) instead of *System.Drawing.Bitmap*.

Comment: But beware: `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource` doesn't play nice with threading.